# Did the robbers from Money Heist real steal noone's money?

Tags: money-supply, central-banking, money

*Money Heist* (original Spanish title: *La Casa de papel*) is a Spanish TV show about a bank heist.

From Wikipedia (bolding mine),

> In Money Heist, a mysterious man, known as "The Professor", is planning the biggest bank heist in history. (...) **The goal is to enter the Royal Mint of Spain in Madrid (...) and print €2.4 billion**.

The idea of the Professor is that, since they don't rob a classic bank, the money they steal is no one's property. I would argue that it is actually everyone's money. Precisely, since we are speaking about euros, it is every European's money. Even if this money belongs to no one, there is still a large sum of money suddenly appearing "out of nowhere".

**In real life, what would be the effect on the economy if the group of robbers carried its plan to its success and ended up with 2.4 billion euros?**

Comment: The easy answer: Inflation in the places where they spend this money. Given that it's not too easy to spend hundreds of million euros at once, the thefts would make sure to spend it over a long period of time. This, in turn, would suggest that the societal costs in terms of annual inflation should not be too high.

Comment: Since EU cease printing 500 bank notes(though the old one is still valid trade note),  with 100 Euro notes, there will be ~20 cubics meter of notes.  Since corruption in the EU zone happens in a scale of 60 billions range, An addition 2.4 billions bank heist hardly make a dent to the region economy.